# How to change text color of a gridViewColumn in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listview, gridviewcolumn

I have A listView In which i want to show items from dataBase. It works fine, But i want to see the items shown in cells as white in a purple listview, How to do it ?

```
<ListView Margin="127,114,227,357" x:Name="lv" Background="purple" >
    <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
          <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Header="First Name" Width="100"  />
         <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}" Header="Last Name" Width="100" />
         <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Email}" Header="Email" Width="100" />
       <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Password}" Header=" Password" Width="100" />
       <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Address}" Header="Address" Width="100" />

      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use DataTemplate and change the text Foreground property, this is one sample for GridViewColumn.

Check on DataTemplate here: [Data Templating Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)

```
<GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Header="First Name" Width="1000">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding FirstName}" Foreground="Purple" />                 
       </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: iTHINK WHEN WE USE DataTemplate then we cant use setter and textblock both, and we dnt have to use DisplayMemberBinding={ Binding Path=FirstName}" in gridviewColumn.
though we can use foreground property in Textblock...it works fine for me.

Comment: ya thats what i have mentioned, please mark it as an answer if it has helped you

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I thought DisplayMemberBinding and CellTemplate were mutually exclusive?

Comment: Also doesn't work for me, the text colour does not change

Answer (score 0):

As per the accepted answer, in order for the `TextBlock` to remain binded and the `Foreground` color to change, the following worked for me:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="1000">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Foreground="Purple" />                 
       </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

and in my case I decided to create a property for the text color and bind to that

```
<GridViewColumn Header="First Name" Width="1000">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock x:Name="Txt" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Foreground="{Binding Path=TextColor}" />                 
       </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

All wrong answers. You simply need to change GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate property.

```html
<ListView ItemsSource="{...}" Foreground="White" >
  <ListView.View>
    <GridView>
      <GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </GridView.ColumnHeaderTemplate>
  <GridViewColumn  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" Header="First Name" Width="1000"/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).